# How can I specify null to foreign keys on parent delete at once in M-V-C Code first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, cascading-deletes

I have many tables which have foreign key relations. Such as Countries and Cities relationship. When I am deleting the country my application is breaking down because I have foreign key relationship. What I want is if user deletes the country, it should get deleted and set forrign keys to null. Following is my code in OnModelCreating Method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Player>().HasOptional(r => r.Team)
        .WithMany(a => a.Players)
        .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.TeamId })
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Problem here is I have 20 to 25 tables I don't want to do it manually. Is there any code which will automatically set cascade false for entire applciation?

Comment: I dont think that is possible...you can remove the child from its parents, not the oposite. unless you set your foreign key on city table as null and do the logic to set null to it when you delete a country

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Then you would have cities with no country.

Comment: @JB06 it is just one table I have other big tables.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Great. How can I set them null? Means if I delete UK then cities should be there with country Id null. I need one logic which will be applied to all the tables no need to do one by one. Is there any?

Comment: The only thing I can think right now is: in your delete method, you get the list of cities in the Country you're about to delete and set the value for each city as null and then you delete the country. I have no other idea beside this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the cascade delete for One-to-many and/or Many-to-many conventions in Code First. Just add either or both of these to your OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

This will disable it, but you can turn cascade delete back on with `.WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` as needed. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.onetomanycascadedeleteconvention(v=vs.113).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.manytomanycascadedeleteconvention(v=vs.113).aspx).

EDIT: If your question is about setting FK to null for a collection, you could do this:

> 1. Make sure you have a collection of cities on the country.
> 2. Expose CountryId as a FK on your City model and make it nullable.
> 3. Set them to null and delete the country.

```
var countryToDelete =  context.Country.Include(c => c.Cities).FirstOrDefault(c => c.CountryId == countryIdToDelete;
countryToDelete.Cities.ForEach(c => c.CountryId = null);
context.Country.Remove(countryToDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I tried this but still it is breaking the application.

Comment: Error: `{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.Cities_dbo.Countries_CountryId\". The conflict occurred in database \"db1\", table \"dbo.Cities\", column 'CountryId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

Comment: OK. Let me try it.

Comment: My country table is linked with 20 tables so will I need to null from all the tables?

Comment: Not Working. `Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

Comment: Drill into to see the error, but it's probably because the FK is not defined as nullable (int?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145213/discussion-between-john-adam-and-steve-greene).